# Is stacking promises leading to a memory leek in node?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

Reading [this thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6673), I started to wonder if what I was doing could end up in a memory leak:

The following code will make me able to stack tasks wherever in my codebase, and make sure that each task is executed only after all the previous ones are done.

```js
function task() {
  //dummy async treatment
  return delay(100);
}
let stack = Promise.resolve('the stack is empty');

function addTask() {
  return stack = stack.then(task);
}
```

When repeatedly calling `addTask` over the time, like every second, will I have a memory leak?
If I do, how should I work around this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When repeatedly calling addTask over the time, like every second, will I have a memory leak? If I do, how should I work around this?

No.  A chain of promises will allow resolved promises earlier in the chain to be garbage collected so as long you are leaving some time for garbage collection, there should be no memory buildup.

The [referenced thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6673) creates a condition where there is no idle time and it is an infinite loop so there could be an accumulation of memory usage if the JS engine always prioritizes firing the handler for a resolved promise over garbage collection.  Since servicing resolved promises is a very high priority operation in most JS engines, it would not surprise me if some JS engines don't do any garbage collection when there's a promise waiting to fire it's `.then()` handler.

Your task handler, on the other hand is not an infinite loop and does have some time for garbage collection (as would most real asynchronous operations).

One thing you should be aware of is that if you were going to create hundreds of thousands of these tasks right away, it will create hundreds of thousands of promises right away which is not the most memory efficient mechanism for scheduling super large numbers of tasks.  For example, just storing them in an array and picking the next one out of the array each time one finishes is probably more memory efficient because a promise object takes more memory than an array element.

On the other hand if you're creating dozens or even hundreds of tasks and you wouldn't have tens of thousands of tasks in the queue at once, then your scheme will work perfectly fine.  As soon as the system does some garbage collection the resolved promises associated with earlier tasks that are now complete will be garbaged collected just  fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your very clear explanation. And I'll keep in mind your suggestion about using an array. I don't think it is necessary in my current case, but it could in some cases.